# Django queryset. Convert output to list

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Box(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user', verbose_name='Owner')
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=30)
    items = models.ManyToManyField('Item', through='BoxItem', blank=True, null=True)

class BoxItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey('Item')
    box = models.ForeignKey('Box')
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name Item", max_length=30)

In [1]: from project.app.models import *

In [2]: b = Box.objects.get(owner=1)

In [3]: b.items_all()

Out[4]: [<Item: PC>, <Item: Notebook>]
```

1. How to convert this Output to list?
2. How to add to this list `quantity` next to the `name` of `Item`? (Example: PC - 3, Notebook- 5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like:

```
 b = Box.objects.get(owner=1)

 [('%s - %s' % (box_item.item.name, box_item.quantity)) for box_item in b.items_all()]
```

Answer (score 0):

In line 4 it appears that the result of `b.items_all()` is actually a [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet); you can use any of the QuerySet's methods; for most purposes (including *list* access) I usually use the QuerySet directly.

In order to have `quantity` shown next to the `name` of `Item` **at Python shell level** you can use the [`__unicode__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#unicode) method at Model level; this should be easy to achieve if you have a one-to-one relationship between `Item` and `BoxItem`; recall that this would result in an additional `join` each time the `__unicode__` function is called.